# Java.security.AccessControlException :access denied error

Tags: html, applet, jnlp, signed

I have copied files from server path to local path using signed applet with client/server socket programming. Its **working fine, if I run Applet separately**.

But its **not working, while accessing a applet in html. Its throw an error:

> Java.security.AccessControlException :access denied (java.io.filePermission /home/user/file1.txt write)

Kindly advise me with examples for how to solve this issue? also Is it possible through jnlp concept?.

Comment: *"run Applet separately."*  What does that entail?  Is it your IDE that is launching the applet?  Are you prompted to accept the digitally signed code?

Answer (score 0):

Emm...

> Its working fine, if I run Applet separately

You mean you run it as a desktop app?

Is your applet signed?

If it is not signed do sign it; If the error still takes place please edit your question to point that;